# PM2 Cluster Mode - Cannot find module 'dotenv/config'

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, pm2

I am trying to run multiple apps using PM2 in cluster mode with config file given below:

```
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "Node APIs",
            "script": "./server",
            "watch": true,
            "node_args": "-r dotenv/config",
            "instances": "max",
            "exec_mode": "cluster"
        },
        {
            "name": "Node Batch",
            "script": "./batch_process",
            "watch": true,
            "node_args": "-r dotenv/config"
        }
    ]
}
```

Node APIs process is getting `errored` in `pm2 list` while Node Batch Process works fine. When I check `~/.pm2/pm2.logs` it says:

`Cannot find module 'dotenv/config'`

I have installed `dotenv` module both locally and globally but still showing same error.

Also PM2 cluster mode works fine in my local machine but on AWS EC2 it shows above error. What am I missing?

`PM2: v4.4.0
NodeJS: v8.12.0`

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the full path to your package in node_modules via the node_args parameter, even if you are already specifying it in cwd.

It will work in cluster mode.

```
   {
      name: 'app-api',
      script: '/full/path/to/app/api.js',
      instances: 2,
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      cwd: '/full/path/to/app',
      node_args: ['-r', '/full/path/to/app/node_modules/dotenv/config'],
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

After ages of looking and experimenting, it seems that it doesn't work in cluster mode, but it does in fork mode. Try running it in fork mode.